# How to store objects of different class in an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have 3 classes. DrawGameComp' and 'GameComp' where 'GameComp' is the base class of 'DrawGameComp'. I have an array of pointers in Game class which is the controlling class. '
    GameComp * components[];    From the  main I have to create a dynamic instance of Game and store add new objects of GameComp and DrawGameComp to the array of pointers of type GameComp.

```
Game Game1(2);                 
Game1.Add(new GameComponent);  
Game1.Add(new DrawableGameComponent);
```

I'v done this part in the main. Because from the main I have to invoke Add passing object as the parameter. When i store these objects I also want assign an id of 1 to the first object and an id of 2 to the second object. How can i include that too.
The Add() function of my Game class is as follows

```
void Game::Add(GameComponent*)
{ 
components[0]=GameComp;
componentCount++;
}
```

but it give me error. I have tried so hard. But I couldn't. Also how do I invoke the Display() member function of these objects in the Array? is it this way?
    components[0]->Display();

Comment: what's the error msg?

Comment: Don't forget that since you are using a base class pointer that you need to make sure the base class method is virtual if you want it to call the derived class method instead.

Comment: How about using a `std::vector` instead of an array? That way you don't need a `componentCount`, and can easily iterate over the items.

Comment: but i have to use an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You probably meant to write the following:

```
void Game::Add(GameComponent* comp)
{ 
    components[componentCount++] = comp;
}
```

2) components[0]->Display() will work, if display is a member function of GameComponent class.

Answer (score 1):

The Add method should look like:

```
void Game::Add(GameComponent* comp)
{ 
    components[componentCount++] = comp;
}
```

Make sure you zero out `componentCount` in the constructor.

Using the array:

```
components[i]->DoSomething();
```

Comment: `comp` is just a name I picked up for the function argument. This means that the function is not recognized. Make sure the declaration has the same signature.